# dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier not calling init method in ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9

I am using a custom header cell, and while it works correctly in ios8, when I try it on an ios9 device the table calls dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier but it doesn't call the initWithFrame (or any init function that I tried) function, and so I just get a blank space for a header file.

Is there a change in how dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier works in ios9 that I should be awear of?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem with a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Changing from initWithFrame to initWithReuseIdentifier solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I could observe the following different behavior under iOS 8 and 9:

Under iOS 8

- initWithReuseIdentifier: gets called first then
- initWithFrame:

whereas under iOS 9
only

- initWithReuseIdentifier:

gets called

Comment: I see the same behavior as you.
It's really strange and checking documentation doesn't say anything about this.
Maybe it's a bug on iOS 9.